# Exclude Value form Dimension

Tags: qlikview

I have this set analysis sentence:

=if(aggr(Rank(Count(WordCounter)),Word)<=70,Word)

I have a request to remove "Among" from the Word data.

Any suggestion?

Comment: This is not a set analysis sentence.Set analysis have the following fomat {<>}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution optimal:
`=if(aggr(Rank(Count {<Word-={'Among'}>}(WordCounter)),Word)<=70,Word)`

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```
=if(aggr(Rank(Count(WordCounter)),if(Word <> 'Among', Word))<=70,Word)
```

Comment: Using set analysis is the best recomended option because using if is bad in time of refresh.